# Who was head of Academy of Fine Arts Vienna in 1907-1908?

Tags: 20th-century, austria

Do we know the names of people who would have made the decision not to admit Hitler in 1907 and 1908? Who was President of the Academy?

Answer (score 14):

[Brigitte Hamann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigitte_Hamann)'s *Hitler's Vienna: A Portrait of the Tyrant as a Young Man* lists the commitee members. (I've also quoted from her book [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/what-were-acceptance-criteria-process-to-the-vienna-fine-arts-academy-in-1906-7)).

> The decision was made by the faculty: professors Rudolf Bacher, Franz
>   Rumpler, Heinrich Lefler, and Kasimiar Pochwalski, but above all, the
>   directors of the two paining schools, Christian Griepenkern and Alois
>   Delug, and, as the faculty's speaker, Siegmund l'Allemand. Most of
>   them had gained their reputations working on the interior decoration
>   of the buildings on the Ring Boulevard. Only the director of the
>   second paining school, Delug, was one of the Modernists; along with
>   Gustav Klimt and Alfred Roller, he was a founding member of the
>   artists' association "Secession". Delug was forever in the midst of
>   argument with his colleagues, and his involvement in the academy was
>   limited. Neither in 1907 nor in 1908 was he in Vienna during
>   examination time: he had declared that he could not accept anyone into
>   his class and had retired to his native South Tyrol for vacation. Thus
>   the other director, the old professor [Griepenkerl](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Griepenkerl) from northern
>   Germany, carried particular weight. He, rather than one of those
>   "Moderns" whom Hitler so despised, had the final say regarding the
>   result of the examination. Speculation tracing Hilter's
>   anti-Seminitism back to his rejection by Jewish Academy professors are
>   entirely unfounded: none of the responsible men during the examination
>   was Jewish. L'Allemand, whose name might lead one to think he was, was
>   from a Protestant, probably Huguenot, family in Hanau, Hesse.